# Stream stories are restricted for this application

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am getting the following error whilst publishing to Facebook via my iPhone application

> Stream stories are restricted for this application.

And I am pretty sure i am not posting any thing to user's wall without notifying him first.Can any suggest what might have caused this issue?
Thank you for your support

Comment: Does your application have the permissions to post to the user's wall?

Comment: How do I check if my application has permissions or not.Usually when user logs in first time from my app.Facebook asks user if he wants this app to Post to his wall and Post to his friends wall etc.What else should i be doing.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that your application has lost its ability to publish to the users by Facebook.  This is usually due to too many people reporting your application as spam or deleting your posts or revoking your application or other spam measures implemented by Facebook.  To appeal to have your app reinstated, [contact Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=dev_disable_appeal).  Another option is to create another application but you may run into the same issue if you dont fix the root cause (people viewing your app as spam).

Comment: Well now that i have tested it I would like people to know about it.what I did was that I created an test app and did some publishing.Then three of my QA reported it as spam.and there it was blocked as well.

Comment: Just to clarify if just 3 people report your app.It gets blocked.How strange is it